# How to dynamically add method calls in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm absolutly stuck trying to dynamically add object methods in a for loop to an already existing object/class.
I want to dynamically add the `order` method for every object existing in the `contactsSorter` array from within a for loop.

I've tried it with `forEach`, with setting the `query =` variable in the for loop and without. Making it to a function and looked for similar cases but wasn't able to fix the issue that it seems to overwrite the query in the for loop.

[Supabase Docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/initializing)

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

// Create a single supabase client for interacting with your database
const supabase = createClient(
  'https://xyzcompany.supabase.co',
  'public-anon-key'
)
// Initialize array to loop over
const contactsSorter = [
    {
      order: "ascend",
      field: "first_name",
      columnKey: "first_name",
    },
    {
      order: "ascend",
      field: "created_at",
      columnKey: "created_at",
    },
];

// Initialize variable i want to modify in for loop
let query = supabase.from("contacts").select("*", { count: "exact" });

if (contactsSorter.length > 0) {
  // Here I want to dynamically add the order by clause to the query  
  for (let i = 0; i < contactsSorter.length; i++) {
    query = query.order(contactsSorter[i].field, {
      ascending: contactsSorter[i].order === "ascend" ? true : false,
    });
  }
} else {
  query = query.order("first_name", {
    ascending: true,
  });
}

let { data: contacts, error, count } = await query;
```

Comment: Need to know what the `class` or object that has methods `.select()` and `order()` look like. Is `supabase` an array or another object/`class`?

Comment: It's an object/ class.

Comment: Ok, post it. `.select("*", { count: "exact" })` is meaningless. Also, `.order(contactsSorter[i].field...` means nothing without the definition of said object/`class`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Your updated comment that the method `.select()` and `.order()` methods are meaningless without the object/ class `supabase` is right. Everything is working fine when I attach everything after each other like so `query.order("first_name").order("created_at")...` but attaching the `order()` methods in a for loop on the `query` doesn't.

Comment: I can't possibly debug something if it's not there. Where in this code is `query` or `supabase` defined? The code as it is in your post is not functional without having define what `query` or `supabase` is. I cannot test code that isn't there nor will I guess and reverse engineer it. If you are chaining methods and expect it to loop then your `this` must change on each iteration probably.

Comment: [Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/initializing) is an API to query a POSTGRESQL database. The error isn't there. As said without the for loop everything is working fine. The problem lies in trying to chain methods in a for loop.

Comment: See last sentence of comment.

Comment: Yes it's about the `this` (query) that would need to change and persist over the loops iterations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248003/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-benjamink).

Comment: To summarize, since all of said data hinges upon a third party API, and it appears that it handles `this` (whatever `this` is) as a single object. If each iteration of an array is a group of different objects then either insatiate a new object on each iteration or use only standard functions and methods. Don't really know because it's not my responsibility to research a third party API when it's not properly explained are tagged in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your example of `contactsSorter` you have exactly 1 element in this array - another array. And this another array consists of two objects.
Apparently you're supposed to have two objects right in `contactsSorter`, so it should be

```
const contactsSorter = [
    {
      order: "ascend",
      field: "first_name",
      columnKey: "first_name",
    },
    {
      order: "ascend",
      field: "created_at",
      columnKey: "created_at",
    }
];
```

Comment: Thank you that was a type in this post. When simplifying the code. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my initial code works like charm. It was just a state dependency missing in my code which caused it to not update. So my original code is correct as it is.

Answer (score -1):

since `.order` function is an asynchronous function, you will have to use `async` `await` or `.then` syntax to use the value returned by query
so you should modify your `for loop` like this:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < contactsSorter.length; i++) {
    query = query.then(async res => {
      return res.order(contactsSorter[i].field, {
        ascending: contactsSorter[i].order === "ascend" ? true : false,
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had a thought that this could be the issue. But after using your code i got `TypeError: res.order is not a function`. I thought it's only nessasy to await at the end because that's where I get the data. `let { data: contacts, error, count } = await query;`

Comment: yes, actually you don't need to use await inside `.then`, I have updated the code you can try this now. as I don't have the implementation of your code so I wasn't able to test it.

Comment: No, `order` needs to be called on the query builder object *before* running the query asynchronously (by calling `.then()`)